# This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 6

Tags: node.js, tensorflow2.0

When I try to run the project, the following message appears:

> node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API
> version 6

How can you fix it?

```
node -v
v12.14.1
npm -v
6.13.4

"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^2.3.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.3.0"
```

Comment: Hi! I see you are a new contributor, welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest adding more information to your question that would make it clearer for another contributors willing to help. Using your example, I would add which OS I'm working on, for example. Maybe add a repo link. SO's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could be two good starting articles

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your version of Node.js.

I just tried this with v12.15.0 and it has the same problem.

I then tried it with v12.18.3 (latest LTS) and it doesn't have the problem.

Note:

- You might need to delete node_modules and do `npm install` again once you have installed the latest version of Node.js.

I recommend that you install nvm (node version manager) so that you can easily change between different versions of Node.js.

- Get it for Linux and MacOS here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
- Get it for Windows here: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows